# How to make Flutter flame components track each other?

Tags: flutter, dart, tracking, flame, fortress

We have a SpriteComponent (_fortress) which is a central object and another SpriteComponent (_player) which moves around _fortress.
we want _fortress to track _player by rotating similar to a typical shooter game (see space fortress game for example).

```dart
    _fortress.add(
        RotateEffect.by(
          _fortress.position.angleTo(_player.position),
          LinearEffectController(1),
          onComplete: () => {},
        ),
      );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to always be tracking the `_player` without any delay you can use the `lookAt` method in your update method:

```dart
class Fortress extends SpriteComponent with HasGameRef<YourGameClass> {
  @override
  double nativeAngle = pi; // You only need to set this if your sprite isn't "looking straight up" in the image, if it is looking to the right it should be `pi` etc.
  
  @override
  void update(double dt) p
    super.update(dt);
    lookAt(gameRef.player.position);
  }
}
```

Comment: It shows me an error: lookAt method is not defined.

Comment: Have you updated to Flame v1.4.0?

Comment: Oops, I had Flame v1.3.0 but I updated it to Flame v1.4.0 and it works now. Thank you so much.